# id like to show column total for one of the columns in my table rendered with django-tables2

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Is there there a way of  showing the totals of a particular column in django-tables2 ?

this is my minimalist model if you need to get my use case:

```
class timekeeper(models.Model):
     begin_time = models.DateTimeField()
     end_time = models.DateTimeField()
     timedelta = models.FloatField()

     def save(self):
         timedelta = end_time-begin_time
```

i have multiple entries, and i would like to total the timedeltas that are in the column.
i saw a discussion on something like [this](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/issues/28), but i could not make head or tails of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this,

```
class timekeeper(models.Model):
     begin_time = models.DateTimeField()
     begin_time = models.DateTimeField()
     ^^ duplicate field, it should be end_time ??
     timedelta = models.FloatField()

     def save(self):
         self.timedelta = self.end_time - self.begin_time
```

Comment: Thats good, but im more interested on the django-tables2 part, how to manipulate the column to show a total at the bottom.